Is there a known geometric interpretation of $\varepsilon^{ijk} M_{ij} v_k$ in three dimensions?
I have run into a computation which, for a given matrix $M\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ and vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, outputs the scalar:
$$ \sum_{ijk} \varepsilon^{ijk} M_{ij} v_k $$
where $\varepsilon^{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol.
Is there a geometric meaning to this quantity? In particular, is there any relation to the triple product?
$$ (a\times b)\cdot c = \sum_{ijk} \varepsilon^{ijk} a_ib_jc_k $$
Or maybe some kind of determinant?

One can think of $b^k = \sum_{ij} \varepsilon^{ijk} M_{ij}$ as a (pseudo)vector, so the quantity you are computing is just the dot product of $b$ and $c$. Is that what you are looking for?

Since we're antisymmetrizing, we can replace $M$ with its antisymmetrization $\frac12(M - M^T)$; so we assume $M$ is antisymmetric. Then this is ($3!$ times) the wedge product of the bivector represented by $M$ with the vector $v$. (I'm assuming you know what that is given the exterior-algebra tag.) In 3D every bivector is simple, so $M_{ij} = \frac12(a_ib_j - a_jb_i)$ for some vectors $a, b$ and
$$
  \sum_{ijk}\epsilon^{ijk}M_{ij}v_k = 3!\,(a\times b)\cdot v.
$$
The vectors $a, b$ are of course not unique. However, we can easily recover $a\times b$ as
$$
  a\times b = \begin{pmatrix}
    M_{23} \\ M_{31} \\ M_{12}
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
If we interpret $M$ as representing a plane with this normal, then of course
$$
  \sum_{ijk}\epsilon^{ijk}M_{ij}v_k = \frac{3!}{\sqrt2}|M||v|\sin(\theta)
$$
where $|M|$ is the Frobenius norm and $\theta$ is the angle between $v$ and the aforementioned plane, and dividing out $3!\,|M|$ gives you the signed volume of the parallelepiped spanned by $v$ and any unit parallelogram in the plane.
